# Is it an option to point to an existing portal site instead of creating a new site during tfs 2010 team project creation?

Tags: wss

We are a small team considering moving to TFS 2010 from Source Safe for richer ALM possibilities rather than just better version control. We intend to benefit from the work items, tasks, portal etc.

It seems to be that TFS 2010 is designed so that there is a one to one relationship between Team Projects and WSS Portal Sites. Is it somehow possible to have a single WSS Portal (v3.0 in my case) with multiple team projects pointing to it?

A well written book, namely "Professional ALM with VS2010 (Wrox 2010)", states on page 526 Chapter 22 that "As you can see, there is an option to point to an existing Web site instead of a new portal site". But the figure shows a different dialog page from an earlier beta possibly.

My concern is that, for a small team of less than 10 people like ours, a single Team Portal would be sufficent for the several projects active at any one time.

Should I go for a single {Team Project + WSS Project Portal} and use areas/iterations for the several different products? What are your relevant experiences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot point to an existing site during the team project creation wizard
2. The granularity of team projects can be indeed per project, or it can be on a higher level (organization / department / ...). There will be advocates for the one and for the other option. In my opinion it depends how related the projects are. If they share the same code base, same documentation or release schedule, then use one team project. If it are totally different products / applications, then use multiple team projects.

That are just my 2 cents.